# CGRectContainsPoint fails in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cgrect

I am using `CGRectContainsPoint` to find whether a point is inside a rect but it always returns false.

If I am wrong please correct me and help me understand whether the point is inside the `CGRect`. Here is my code:

```
    BOOL isObjectInside = false;

    CGPoint serverPoint = CGPointMake(78,157);

    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(31, 207, 98, 28);


    if(CGRectContainsPoint(frame, serverPoint))
    {
        isObjectInside = true;
    }
    else
    {
        isObjectInside = false;

    }
```

Comment: the y position of your serverPoint is 157, but your frame starts only at 207. So it doesn't contain the point. Try giving 210 or something for the y position of the serverPoint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a rendering of your view hierarchy:

[image]

Note that the red dot is not inside the yellow square.

Therefore, it's expected that `CGRectContainsPoint` would return `NO` / `false`.

Comment: If I get  (x,y) from server I have to find the object that contains the x,y by itreating through each view  present in the window

Comment: Are you looking for `hitTest:withEvent:`?

Comment: `frame` doesn't contain `serverPoint`, so it's correct that `CGRectContainsPoint` returns `NO`. Anything else you didn't ask in your question.

Comment: no just finding the whether the objects present in a UIViewController have points which are passed from the server

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70683/discussion-between-user3115014-and-aaron-brager).

Comment: Didn't you [already ask that a week ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28341696/find-the-object-from-x-y-in-ios)? Did you also read [How to get UIView given a CGPoint](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6033220/1445366)?

Comment: that wont work in my case as I am building a static library and I am unable to get reference to the base view .Instead it comes as UILayoutContainerView

Comment: You should post a new question with whatever your actual question is.